# JQuery/Javascript animate div zoom out and back in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate zoom out and zoom back in on a div with a small delay between using jquery

I'm fairly a newb and the code I've tried either loops the animation or the delay before zooming back in is too long. My current code is below, but the delay comes across more like 4000 rather than 10.

```
                            document.getElementById("pedigree-column-gen2").style.display = "inline-block";
                            $('#pedigree-viewer').animate({ 'zoom': 0.5}, 400);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#pedigree-viewer").animate({ 'zoom': 1}, 400);
                            }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using `.delay(10)`?

For exemple with your code:

```js
$('#pedigree-viewer').animate({'zoom': 0.5}, 400).delay(100).animate({'zoom': 1}, 400)
```

I've put 100 because the value in the delay function is in miliseconds, but feel free to adjust it to your needs

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried that as well but the animation just continues to loop. If I add a .stop(false) at the end, then the animation flickers.

Comment: Have you removed the setTimout ?

Comment: I just had to resolve an issue with my loop and am good now. Thank you so much.